# PHP Pagination using SELECT COUNT (*) as

Tags: php, sql, pagination

Hi stackoverflow readers and staff, I have a problem using a pagination code. 
All is fine when I'm using SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name, but when I try to SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE marca=nokia, To paginate just results containing "nokia" word in line "marca" from an table named "modele" and I receive an error: "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in E:\server\htdocs\pag.php on line 17"

This is the frame of code:

```
$marca = $_GET['marca'];
/* 
   First get total number of rows in data table. 
   If you have a WHERE clause in your query, make sure you mirror it here.
*/
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE marca=$marca";
$total_pages = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
$total_pages1 = $total_pages['num'];

/* Setup vars for query. */
$targetpage = "paginare.php";   //your file name  (the name of this file)
$limit = 5;                                 //how many items to show per page
$page = $_GET['pagina'];
if($page) 
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          //first item to display on this page
else
    $start = 0;                             //if no page var is given, set start to 0

/* Get data. */
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name LIMIT $start, $limit";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;                  //if no page var is given, default to 1.
$prev = $page - 1;                          //previous page is page - 1
$next = $page + 1;                          //next page is page + 1
$lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);      //lastpage is = total pages / items per page, rounded up.
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      //last page minus 1

/* 
    Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. 
    We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
*/
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class=\"pagination\">";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$prev\">« Inapoi</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">« Inapoi</span>";   

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$counter\">$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lpm1\">$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=$lastpage\">$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=1\">1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?pagina=2\">2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class=\"current\">$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$counter\">$counter</a>";                 
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href=\"$targetpage?page=$next\">Inainte »</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class=\"disabled\">Inainte »</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
```

And here my php is ending, sorry for bad english and thank you in advance. Marcel

Comment: have you tired to echo the query

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: as with every OTHER duplicate on this site: you get that error because a query failed, you assumed it succeeded, and blindly plowed on ahead using that failed query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any string in SQL needs to be surrounded by " or '.
Like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE marca='{$marca}'";
```

With the resulting query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM $tbl_name WHERE marca='nokia'
```

Comment: now i am receiving this error: Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in E:\server\htdocs\pag.php on line 37 wich is: $lastpage = ceil($total_pages/$limit);

Comment: Because `$total_pages` in an array. You want to use `$total_pages1` :)

Comment: Thankyou Vlad (Si eu sunt Roman ca tine si i-mi face o imensa placere sa vad ca un Roman ajuta un alt Roman dar si alti mici programatori care vor citi discutia noastra), RESPECT!